# How can I add another WHERE filter to a PostGIS query?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, sql, syntax

I have this query, which works well, for an OSM database:

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM (
  SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(lg.geometry, bbox.geom), 4326))::json As geometry,
  (
    SELECT row_to_json(t)
    FROM (
      SELECT name, type, admin_level
    ) t
  )
As properties
FROM
  osm_admin As lg,
  (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(10.735445022583008, 59.913428634991995,
      10.776472091674805, 59.933989460416115, 4326),3857) as geom) as bbox
    WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geometry, bbox.geom)
  ) fc;
```

I'd like to filter this generic query a bit, depending on the zoom level. E.g. I'd like to add filter for zoom level `WHERE admin_level < 4`. I also need to add other filters for other queries, based on this template (where `admin_level` is a property of the `osm_admin` table).

Where can I insert such a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: have you tried `WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geometry, bbox.geom) AND admin_level < 4`?

Comment: I hadn't, but that works swimmingly! *Embarassed...* Thanks! Feel free to write up an answer that I can accept.

Comment: Is it really worth it because it is so trivial? No bad feelings for you, everybody forgets the basics every now and then.

Comment: @user30184 I know it might be trivial, but it might be worth adding the answer so that the question doesn't get recycled periodically.  Also it could also of been added at the end `...) fc WHERE admin_level < 4;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add `WHERE ST_Intersects(lg.geometry, bbox.geom) AND admin_level < 4`. This will give you the result for those features which intersect with the given geometry AND whose admin_level is less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AND` in your `WHERE` clause...